# Проблема с скриптом при запуске игры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Из-за чего может быть следующее: скрипт висит на объекте, при старте сцены он выключается ? то есть  enable = false, манипуляции с активностью скрипта нигде не прописана

Comment: `манипуляции с активностью скрипта нигде не прописана` - значит всё же прописана. Включайте отладку и вперед... Подсказка: в отладчике можно задавать условия, например, триггерить остановку при отключении объекта

Comment: Как написал предыдущий комментатор: воспользуйтесь отладкой. Если какие-то проблемы с этим, можете даже просто в коде прописать в Start() в OnEnable() что-то типа Debug.Log("<название метода из которого вызываете> script.enamble=" + this.enable); Хотя лучше действительно поставить просто точки остановки. Подозреваю, что или не тот скрипт подключен, или где-то из другого места вы его выключаете.